# Unable To debug with AppCode after upgrading to Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, appcode

After I updated Xcode to 7.3 I am unable to start debugging with AppCode 3.3.2 & 3.3.3 I am just able to Run without debugging each time I start debbuging with appcode this happens in the console:

**/Users/labib/Library/Caches/AppCode33/DerivedData/TestApp-e195af2c/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TestApp.app**

**Stopping simulator session...**

**Simulator session started with process 3047**

**Process finished with exit code 0**

Comment: same here. Try the EAP version, seems to work for now

Comment: @ahmedlabib did the XCode update drop last night?  **EDIT:** Nm, I just checked my update logs and saw that it hit this morning.

Comment: @AndreiS Thank you, The EAP version works with Xcode 7.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JetBrains is aware of this issue and have a fix as part of the current RC ([see their latest AppCode blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/2016/03/appcode-2016-1-rc2/)).

Their current advice is essentially to download the RC version from their [AppCode EAP page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/OBJC/AppCode+EAP) if you've already upgraded to XCode 7.3.  **NOTE:** It does require a license or you can use a 30 day eval period.